# Brewing in an oversized kit - any risks?

Tags: equipment, boil-equipment

I'm looking at buying a larger brew kit to go alongside the current 27L setup I currently have.

I've been toying with the idea of upgrading to 200L and simply not brewing to capacity, maybe brew around 120L at a time or 80L at a time, or even as low as 50L at a time.

The question is, are there any risks with boiling in an oversized kit? Will there be a risk of the evaporating DMS condensing on the walls and dripping back in or will that be such a minute amount as to be unimportant? Or perhaps something else I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should have very small or no risk boiling smaller kits in a bigger kettle, it may not be as efficient and it maybe harder to clean. but the result would be same if not similar to using a smaller kettle.

I use a 16 gallon/64L Kettle, and I have not had any issue making smaller batches in it. I have brewed a 2 gallon batch on my system with out issue.